# Fail to PUT second data in mongodb via Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am using Angularjs to update the following expressjs Team model, but one weird thing is that when I PUT the first one to the database, it works.

```
var TeamSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    image: String,
    homeColor: String,
    guestColor: String,
    thirdColor: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

If the database consists of exactly one data, it will have the following errors:

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: acleague.teams.$prefix_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: acleague.teams.$prefix_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1399820159 },
  connectionId: 69575,
  ok: 1 }
```

I can sure that I don't have an $prefix_1 attr for team model.

Anyone can help me solve this problem? It already spends me lots of time of it.

Comment: The easiest fix would be to drop the `prefix_1` index if you're not using it.

Comment: I am new to mongodb and not sure what is the concept behind it. What is prefix_1 for and where it is defined? and how can I disable it? Thanks for answering

Comment: It's nothing standard, so it must be an index that was added to that collection at some point.  You can drop it in the shell using: `db.teams.dropIndex('prefix_1')`

Comment: can I run the command inside angularjs or expressjs? or I just need to run it once in the mongodb shell?

Comment: Just run it once in the MongoDB shell.